# Liquibase error while creating Postgres function

Tags: postgresql

When I execute the below Postgres function in pgadmin, it works fine but when executed through liquibase code, it throws the error:
*Unterminated dollar quote started at position 274 in SQL CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION*

Can someone please help what am I missing here? tia

*Postgres version: **42.2.15***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_data(param_bic character varying, param_countrycode character varying, param_nationalid character varying, param_iban_countrycode character varying, param_iban character varying, ref1 refcursor)
 RETURNS refcursor
AS $BODY$
    declare select_statement text default 'select bic.bic, bic.chips_uid, bic.national_id, bic.institution_name, bic.pob_number,
        bic.street_address_1, bic.street_address_2, bic.street_address_3, bic.street_address_4, bic.city, bic.cps, bic.zip_code,
        bic.country_name, bic.iso_country_code, iban.iban_bic, bic.record_key
        from swift_ref_bic bic left join swift_ref_iban iban on iban.record_key = bic.iban_key ';
    WHERE_STATEMENT text DEFAULT ' WHERE 1=1 ';
begin
    IF PARAM_IBAN is not null
        THEN WHERE_STATEMENT := CONCAT(WHERE_STATEMENT , ' AND iban.IBAN_NATIONAL_ID like ' , '''' , PARAM_IBAN , '%' , '''');
        END IF;
    IF PARAM_NATIONALID is not null
        THEN WHERE_STATEMENT := CONCAT(WHERE_STATEMENT , ' AND bic.NATIONAL_ID like ' , '''' , PARAM_NATIONALID , '%' , '''');
        END IF;
    IF PARAM_IBAN_COUNTRYCODE is not null
        THEN WHERE_STATEMENT := CONCAT(WHERE_STATEMENT , ' AND iban.IBAN_ISO_COUNTRY_CODE like ' , '''' , PARAM_IBAN_COUNTRYCODE , '%' , '''');
        END IF;
    IF PARAM_COUNTRYCODE is not null
        THEN WHERE_STATEMENT := CONCAT(WHERE_STATEMENT , ' AND bic.ISO_COUNTRY_CODE like ' , '''' , PARAM_COUNTRYCODE , '%' , '''');
        END IF;
    IF PARAM_BIC is not null
        THEN WHERE_STATEMENT := CONCAT(WHERE_STATEMENT , ' AND bic.BIC like ' , '''' , '%' , PARAM_BIC , '%' , '''');
        ELSEIF PARAM_NATIONALID IS NOT NULL AND PARAM_COUNTRYCODE IS NULL AND PARAM_IBAN_COUNTRYCODE IS NULL AND PARAM_IBAN IS NULL THEN WHERE_STATEMENT := ' WHERE 1 != 1 ';
        ELSEIF PARAM_NATIONALID IS NULL AND PARAM_COUNTRYCODE IS NULL AND PARAM_IBAN_COUNTRYCODE IS NULL AND PARAM_IBAN IS NULL THEN WHERE_STATEMENT := ' WHERE 1 != 1 ';
        END IF;
  SELECT_STATEMENT :=  CONCAT (SELECT_STATEMENT, WHERE_STATEMENT) ;
    open ref1 for execute (SELECT_STATEMENT);
  return ref1;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

Comment: Are you using `splitStatements=false` in your change set?

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. This looks like a very interesting question. However, it seems to be an issue with the liquibase version control program/system and as such is not a very good match for our community. You might be better off asking over on the Stack Overflow site. They even have a [`liquibase`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/liquibase/info) tag and a [couple of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liquibase) that have already been asked. Good luck.